# Homebrew won't brew any more

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

On my MacMini with El Capitan I can't run brew any more. I get the following Error:

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/config.rb:34:in `initialize': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/config.rb:34:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/config.rb:34:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:10:in `<main>'
```

The permissions of /usr/local are correct.

The config.rb file, which I haven't changed looks like this:

```
def cache
  if ENV["HOMEBREW_CACHE"]
    Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_CACHE"]).expand_path
  else
    # we do this for historic reasons, however the cache *should* be the same
    # directory whichever user is used and whatever instance of brew is executed
    home_cache = Pathname.new("~/Library/Caches/Homebrew").expand_path
    if home_cache.directory? && home_cache.writable_real?
      home_cache
    else
      Pathname.new("/Library/Caches/Homebrew").extend Module.new {
        def mkpath
          unless exist?
            super
            chmod 0775
          end
        end
      }
    end
  end
end

HOMEBREW_CACHE = cache
undef cache

# Where brews installed via URL are cached
HOMEBREW_CACHE_FORMULA = HOMEBREW_CACHE+"Formula"

unless defined? HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE
  HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE = ENV["HOMEBREW_BREW_FILE"] || which("brew").to_s
end

# Where we link under
HOMEBREW_PREFIX = Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_PREFIX"])

# Where .git is found
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY = Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY"])

HOMEBREW_LIBRARY = Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_LIBRARY"])
HOMEBREW_CONTRIB = HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY/"Library/Contributions"

# Where we store built products
HOMEBREW_CELLAR = Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_CELLAR"])

HOMEBREW_LOGS = Pathname.new(ENV["HOMEBREW_LOGS"] || "~/Library/Logs/Homebrew/").expand_path

HOMEBREW_TEMP = Pathname.new(ENV.fetch("HOMEBREW_TEMP", "/tmp"))

unless defined? HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH
  HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH = Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath.parent.join("Homebrew")
end

HOMEBREW_LOAD_PATH = HOMEBREW_LIBRARY_PATH
```

The same error occurs with brew, brew doctor, brew update etc.

Any ideas, what could be wrong?

Comment: Could you edit your question with `more /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/config.rb` ?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I had the same issue - seemed to be the result of a brew update that could not complete due to permissions issues.

First I reset the repo to the latest head:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Then I could run:

```
brew doctor
```

Which found permissions issues. Fixing those permissions as per instructions finally allowed me to run:

```
brew update
```

Comment: That was probably the reason for my issue too. The previous version of Sophos messed up with the permissions in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/share. Just updating the permissions with sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin and .../share didn't help me.

Comment: Yep, my issue starts with Sophos as well. And keeps doing it :|

Comment: You need Sophos 9.4 which still is in Preview state.

Comment: I got hundreds of these messages after performing the steps above: `Error: Failed to import: xxxxyyyzzz
undefined method 'desc' for Formulary::Formulae::XxxxYyyZzz:Class` so I `cd ~` and tried it again and everything worked great!  Good tip, helped me out.

Answer (score 6):

OS X messes up permissions with every update.

Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man/man1
```

and

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/man
```

and ensure that the current user (the one running `brew`) has permission to access `/usr/local`.

Comment: In my case it wasn't OSX but Sophos that messed up the permissions. With version 9.4.1 they fixed that bug.

Comment: That's interesting! I have Sohpos 9.2.9 and it's not been causing problems. Although mine is not the Home version.

Answer (score 2):

I replaced the script /usr/local/bin/brew with the new version I found on github. Now everything is fine again.

The latest file, of which, can be found here:

- https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/bin/brew

Answer (score 0):

A little dirty but I just uninstalled homebrew and reinstalled. WARNING: This will uninstall all brew installed packages.

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
$ sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to run `brew upgrade` (NOT `brew update`). You might encounter some permissions issues as mentioned in some of the other answers. It will suggest some commands to fix that.

After the permission issue is fixed, running `brew upgrade` fixed the issue. It is apparently not an uncommon issue when updating OS - Read about it on the [official Homebrew Documenation](https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues).